# find the minimal polynomial of T. $V= M_{n \times n}(R)$ and $T(A)=A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> For each linear operator T on V, find the minimal polynomial of T.
>   $V= M_{n \times n}(R)$ and $T(A)=A^t$.

I noticed that $T^2=I$, but then how I am supposed to follow from here?

Comment: so, you have that a polynomial that vanishes T is $x^2-1$. The minimal polynomial should be a divisor of this, but $x-1$ nor $x+1$ vanish T. So, $x^2-1$ has to be minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T^2=I$, then $T^2-I=(T+I)(T-I)=\bf0$ and the minimal polynomial is a factor of $t^2-1$. $T=\pm I$ clearly does not match the description $T(A)=A^T$, so the minimal polynomial is not $t\pm1$; it has to be $t^2-1$.